# Make image visible or not visible based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

The following code turns an image on or off based on whether there are two checkboxes checked.  The problem is as I add checkboxes only the last two work correctly.  In the example below the image does not turn on and off if `chk_Pipe1N` and `chkIn1` are both checked.  However it works perfectly when `chk_Pipe2N` and `chkIn2` are both checked.  If I add `chk_Pipe3N` and `chkIn3` it will work for this set, but set 1 and 2 no longer work.  Any ideas why?

```
'NIn
If Me.chk_Pipe1N Or Me.chk_Pipe2N And Me.chkIn1 Or Me.chkIn2 Then
    Me.imgNIN.Visible = True
Else
    Me.imgNIN.Visible = False
End If

'NOut
If Me.chk_Pipe1N Or Me.chk_Pipe2N And Me.chkOut1 Or Me.chkOut2 Then
    Me.imgNOut.Visible = True
Else
    Me.imgNOut.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Is this the logic you want? `If (Me.chk_Pipe1N Or Me.chk_Pipe2N) And (Me.chkIn1 Or Me.chkIn2) Then`

Comment: Chrismas007, this worked, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Simpler (adding @HansUp's comment):

```
Me.imgNIN.Visible = (Me.chk_Pipe1N Or Me.chk_Pipe2N) And _
                    (Me.chkIn1 Or Me.chkIn2)
```